# Adding noise to image for deep learning, yes or no?

Tags: deep-learning

I've been thinking that adding noise to an image can prevent overfitting and also "increase" the dataset by adding variations to it. I'm only trying to add some random 1s to images that has shape (256,256,3) which uses uint8 to represent its color. I don't think that can affect the visualization at all (I showed both images with matplotlib and they seems almost the same) and has only ~0.01 mean difference in the sum of their values.

But it doesn't look to have its advances. After training for a long time it's still not as good as the one doesn't use noises.

Has anyone tried to use noise for image classification tasks like this? Is it eventually better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't go to add noise to your data. Some papers employ input deformations during training to increase robutness and convergence speed of models. However, these deformations are statistically inefficient (not just on image but any kind of data). 
You can read [Intriguing properties of Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6199v1.pdf) from Szegedy et *al.* for more details (and refer to references 9 & 13 for papers that uses deformations).

If you want to avoid overfitting, you might be interested to read about [regularization](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/regularization.html) instead.

Comment: Indeed my results weren't good at all. Should try regularization for the next one

Comment: @MonSh1rE I'll be interested to have some update if any of our proposal helped you

Answer (score 1):

Yes you may add noise to extend your dataset and avoid overfitting your training set but make sure it is random otherwise your network will take this noise as something it should learn (and that's not something you want). I wouldn't use this method first to do that, I would first rotate and/or flip my samples.

However, your network should perform better or, at least, as well as your previous network.

First thing I would check is : How do you measure your performances ? What were your performances before and after ? And did you change anything else ?

Comment: Yes they are random noises and they're randomly generated everytime I load batches. F2 score is the standard in this case, my previous performance was 0.88 but this one is around 0.74 but it's still training when I type this. The latter takes way longer though

Comment: You have extended your dataset so you heve more samples in your dataset so you have more step to complete an entire epoch so I think it is expected to take longer to train :)

Comment: Oups I read wrong. So you don't really extend your dataset. You just always modify it. I don't know if that's the way you should do it. I'm going to check :)

Comment: Yes I'm just keep adding very small noises. That paper Thomas Pinetz gave says it has no effect. I'm going to try it out anyway

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of works that deal with this problem. Because you make the training set harder the training error will be lower, however your generalization might be better. It has been shown that adding noise can have stability effects for training Generative Adversarial Networks ([Adversarial Training](https://c4209155-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/nips2016adversarial/WAT16_paper_35.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cobNEKmoWjNBHmgxeMfiyFr0oIuVnlRxknz7M6HSru8m0ELxGAm-mZRawxMB8QAn2TbRt1bnJpXLtTXJUgh8qcikaVHC3LC3B60GkJk-lJMC-amVmxOlUJmeTf3KfIqdcPvLjSCDbAnq2WzBOOl-GxICiFru007Q8nLhvjlffuqfNv5AAIapHMEz71oQ9gvQbrAcWnb_KS47ZAofSYXyyorCGgyE5DtrhDwLYXDidGR4i2ZOOc%3D&attredirects=0)).

For classification tasks it is not that cut and dry. Not many works have actually dealt with this topic. The closest one is to my best knowledge is this one from google (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6572.pdf), where they show the limitation of using training without noise. They do report a regularization effect, but not actual better results than using other methods.

Comment: "in many cases the noise will have essentially no effect rather than yielding a more difficult input" is what I saw in the paper :(   Still don't quite believe it personally. Maybe I should train the net for a bit longer to find out

Comment: I sincerely hope that you do find performance improvements and I am hoping to read a paper from you on the topic, if you do manage to improve generalization. However, to my best knowledge no one ever managed to do so. This does not mean that it's impossible of course.